# How to compare values of two JSON?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have two JSON and I would like to comparison their value. How can I do it?

Example:

```
volume_id=["1","2","3"];

$json_volumes_id=["2","4","5"];
```

My Models:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('workers_properties');
$this->db->like("volume_id","\"$json_volumes_id\"");
$result_1 = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: write sql query you want to get

Comment: volume_id is column

Comment: my table(workers_properties):                                                                                 id | volume_id                                                                                                                           and my volume_id is ["1","2","3"]

Comment: convert into array after that use `where_in` instead of like

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use json_decode() function to convert json into array and then you can easily comparison their value.